# Getting specific headers along with other body data in Users.thread: get

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

You can very easily select what headers you want in a Users.thread: get-request, like so:

```
format = metadata
metadataHeaders = From

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/14eaffaf5e3e8242?metadataHeaders=From&format=metadata&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "id": "14eaffaf5e3e8242",
 "historyId": "510358",
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14eaffaf5e3e8242",
   "threadId": "14eaffaf5e3e8242",
   "labelIds": [
    "SENT",
    "INBOX",
    "IMPORTANT"
   ],
   "snippet": "Wow Emil!",
   "historyId": "510292",
   "internalDate": "1437471536000",
   "payload": {
    "mimeType": "multipart/mixed",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "From", // I just got the header I asked for.
      "value": "Emil Tholin <emtholin@gmail.com>"
     }
    ]
   },
   "sizeEstimate": 9260
  }, ...
}
```

You can also get certain parts of the body very easily. E.g. here I ask for the attachmentIds of all the attachments in the message body:

```
field = messages/id,messages/payload/parts/body/attachmentId

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads/14eaffaf5e3e8242?fields=messages%2Fid%2Cmessages%2Fpayload%2Fparts%2Fbody%2FattachmentId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14eaffaf5e3e8242",
   "payload": {
    "parts": [
     {
      "body": {  // This message had an attachment.
       "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ_0lphTo48BO0xBT_YOSo3tYah23hzpjyATe3GwfziK0I6401P_8-ZYoGuCQPHhpPP0-S_pjL68WIEZzQ0tu72RcIOE4UY3kA4u8PjXPf3Cm5PxVJjmH9N0hm0fFX31RYo8bfZQ6l7bDbYbnCSZbckG7g8enGaKMPbBzIEEC4HXr_YghOYWSfrXKXiFLnxWN4LfsFk3IXUN2tVvMe_0xMhDDfBlqYPnXHr2PhPghq7bQojNxiH4YziIqaKmwiU4xqVfygbae-K-_Q2blyz0EgI4OXjMzwz56Q5e1w"
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "id": "14eaffb277b61cd0" // This message had no attachment.
  }, ...
 ]
}
```

As you can see in the first request, no part of the body is retrieved when asking for specific metadata headers. Individual fields are also hard to pick out in the `fields`-parameter, since headers are not key-value pairs, but objects on the form `{ "name": <HEADER_NAME>, "value": <HEADER_VALUE> }`.

Is there any way to combine these two requests? I would like to get all the relevant metadata about a message at the same time as getting how many attachments there are in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Users.threads.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get).

> "metadata": Returns email headers with message metadata such as identifiers and labels.

The fields parameter is only used to limit the amount of data returned. Since `metadata` mode is already a limited response you can't use fields to get data outside of that subset. Your best option would be to use your second example with fields and then filter the metadata values locally.

Comment: Thank you for your reply abraham. I sent a few messages to my Gmail account from my Office365 account, and the headers were atrocious. I'm just worried it might be a little to much data, but maybe it's not an issue? I just implemented two parallel batch requests, where one fetches the relevant headers, and the other fetches the attachmentIds. Maybe that is worse?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by atrocious and how the connections are handled. E.g. if the connections are happening over HTTP/2 than two requests might be faster. Generally though a single request with a little more data is going to be faster than two requests.

Comment: Atrocious in the way that there are a lot of them. Yeah, you are probably right. I was worried that it might be to much unnecessary header data. But since I cache the messages, that is not a huge issue either I guess. The precious quota runs up pretty quickly by getting every message twice just to get a few less headers, that's for sure.

Comment: I will try to do one batch request and see how that adds up. Thank you very much for your time. Also, that is one mighty fine beard. Very jealous.